# How do I use the data collected of one function in another function

Tags: python, function

So basically I'm a pure beginner trying to do this school assignment.

```
def function1():
   while True:
     choice1 = (input("Random text")).lower()
     if choice1 in ('option1', 'option2'):
       break
     else: 
       print("Even more random text")
   return choice1
def function2():
   rightEvenOdd = 'random word'
   if choice1 == rightEvenOdd:
     print('Yay')
   else: 
     print('Not yay')

NameError: name 'choice1' is not defined
```

The second function can't access the variable locked in the first function and I don't know how to get it to access it. Plz help.

Comment: You can just put that variable you want outside the function to make it global.

Comment: @bichanna but the variable changes throughout the use of the program. I didn't want to put the whole program in because it was really long. But, long story short the user keeps using these functions until a variable reaches a certain value.

Answer (score 0):

function2 can't access it because choice1 is a [Local Variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable). In python, any variable created in a function is a local variable by default. You could override this by assigning choice1 as a [global variable](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_global_variables.asp). Also, read these guidelines for styling your code. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 0):

`choice1` variable is defined in `function1`, but not in `function2` where you also use it.

One option, and avoid using globals, is to pass the result of `function1` into `function2` as a parameter, then `function2` can use it.

```
def function1():
   while True:
     choice1 = (input("Random text")).lower()
     if choice1 in ('option1', 'option2'):
       break
     else: 
       print("Even more random text")
   return choice1

def function2(choice1): #function2 receives the choice1 value
   rightEvenOdd = 'random word'
   if choice1 == rightEvenOdd:
     print('Yay')
   else: 
     print('Not yay')


choice1 = function1()  # assign result of function1 to a variable

function2(choice1)     # pass the new value to function2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function 1 into function 2 as you already return choice1 value from function1.
For example :

```
def function2(): 
    choice1 = function1()
    rightEvenOdd = 'random word'
    if choice1 == rightEvenOdd:
     print('Yay')
    else: 
     print('Not yay')
```